# Product of measure spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that B(R^n)=B(R)*B(R)*B(R)...n times where B(R) is a Borel sigma algebra of R.

I know B(R^n) subset of B(R)*B(R)*B(R)..
But I couldn't get idea of reverse inclusion. Please help me out.

Comment: This depends a bit on how you define the product measure, and how you define the product of sigma-algebras. Royden and Fitzpatrick for instance don't bother with defining the product sigma-algebra and product measure except for the complete case. Others (including, presumably, the author of your book) separately define the product sigma-algebra and its completion.

Comment: At this point we don't have measure we just have measure spaces. How can I prove

Comment: How do you define the product of $\sigma$-algebras? It cannot be simply the product of sets, because for example a disk is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but cannot be written as a product of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here, products of two measures space is just rectangular set. i.e A*B form

Comment: Then as far as I can tell your result is just false, by considering the preceding example. Are you sure that your product of $\sigma$-algebras is not actually defined as the minimal $\sigma$-algebra containing the Cartesian product? (In this case your equality would indeed hold, although the proof is not trivial.)

Comment: Can you share me some outline of proof.

Comment: The first idea is that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent. So we can consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the max norm. Here the "balls" are actually square prisms, so $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains all square prisms. So you now need to prove that the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains all square prisms is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains all products of Borel subsets of the reals.

Comment: (Cont.) Since rectangular prisms can be easily written as unions of square prisms, this amounts to showing that the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains all products of Borel subsets of the reals is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains all products of open subsets of the reals.

Comment: @Ian Please repost as an answer, now that you have already written so much.

Answer (score 0):

The product of two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ on sets $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ is denoted by $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$. It is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathfrak{A} \times \mathfrak{B}$ such that if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$ then $A \times B \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$. This is not the same as $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$ (which has pairs of sets as its elements, which is not what we want). More interestingly, it is not always the same as $\{ A \times B : A \in \mathcal{A},B \in \mathcal{B} \}$, although it always contains this set. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a disk is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, but it is not a product of two measurable subsets of the line.

We *do* have that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, however. This is ultimately because $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the product topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. The same thing happens with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that there is a little bit of an issue with terminology here, since some authors do not study product $\sigma$-algebras *per se*. Instead, starting from a measure space, they build the product measure space through the the Caratheodory construction. The resulting $\sigma$-algebra is the *completion* of the product $\sigma$-algebra as I defined it above, but it is often called the product $\sigma$-algebra.